# How to change the part of array key?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've following array titled `$_FILES`:

```
Array
(
    [document_file_name_2] => Array
        (
            [name] => FAQ.doc
            [type] => application/msword
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpDnXqMX
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 35840
        )

    [document_file_name_5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pay Slip-Sushil Kadam-June 2013.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php97sAKI
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 39648
        )

)
```

As this array is generated dynamically it's length may vary. Now what I want to achieve is change some part of existing array key. i want to make the array key start from the key `[document_file_name_0]` and so on. The following array should come after doing manipulation. Can anyone help me how should I achieve this? Following is the desired `$_FILES` array:

```
Array
    (
        [document_file_name_0] => Array
            (
                [name] => FAQ.doc
                [type] => application/msword
                [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpDnXqMX
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 35840
            )

        [document_file_name_1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Pay Slip-Sushil Kadam-June 2013.pdf
                [type] => application/pdf
                [tmp_name] => /tmp/php97sAKI
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 39648
            )

    )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray=array();
$fileNum=0;
foreach ($originalArray as $file) {
    $newArray["document_file_name".$fileNum++]=$file;
}
```

The content of $newArray should be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Get the values in the array using array_values

Create a new array and loop through the array_values and set in the new array your 
    custom_key => value pair

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
  if ($key != 'document_file_name_' . $counter) { // If by coincidence this one is correct already, no need to rename/delete the original
    $array['document_file_name_' . $counter] = $array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
  $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the best (according to the OP) question is selected, but I'm still eager to say that you could use almost EVERY php loop for this:

**[foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)** by @RubenSerrate

```
$newArray=array();
$fileNum=0;
foreach ($originalArray as $file) {
    $newArray["document_file_name".$fileNum++]=$file;
}
```

**[for()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)** ([phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/q7r-5b3))

```
$newArr = array();
$length = count($_FILES);
for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
    $newArr["document_file_name_".$i] = array_shift($_FILES);
}
```

**[while()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)**

```
$newArr = array();
$i=0;
while ($_FILES) {
    $newArr["document_file_name_".$i] = array_shift($_FILES);
    $i++;
}
```

+ all other examples + all other yet not mentioned methods.

Just learn PHP and good luck!